# The charecter " is giving me an error in discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code:

```
async def on_guild_channel_update(before, after):
    channel = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name="bot-logs")
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Channel Name Updated", description="A channel name was updated.")
    embed.add_field(name="Old name", value=f"The old name was: {before}.", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="New name", value=f"The old name was: {after}.", inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

and I get this error
[image: yt]

other people are saying it should work fine but does anyone know why this doesn't work for me?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I believe you'd see this if you're using Python 2.x by default instead of 3.x.

Comment: I dont know how do i find out?

Comment: Run `python --version`

Comment: ok i am using Python 3.5.3

Comment: f-strings where introduced in Python 3.6, that's why you get this error.

Comment: How do i update @ThierryLathuille ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you have python 3.5, and f strings were introduced in 3.6 To upgrade, go to python.org and download the version of python 3.6+(would suggest 3.8.3). Then run it, as you already have python installed, you can click on the upgrade now button and it will install it on your computer. Hoping you have windows, I don't know if it works in mac/linux